# Seleniumwire get Response text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I'm using Selenium-wire to try and read the request response text of some network traffic. The code I have isn't fully reproducable as the account is behind a paywall.

The bit of selenium-wire I'm currently using using is:

```
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        # The body is in bytes so convert to a string
        body = driver.last_request.body.decode('utf-8')
        # Load the JSON
        data = json.loads(body)
```

Unfortunately though, that is reading the payload of the request
[image]

and I'm trying to parse the Response:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `last_request`'s `response`:

```
body = driver.last_request.response.body.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(body)
```

Comment: Thanks Yevhen, instead of the last request, would you know how I can get the second to last one?

Comment: You should be able to get it with `driver.requests[-2]`.

Comment: don't decode manually, just use `response.json()`

Comment: @wim It looks like it is the `selenium-wire`'s own implementation of [`Response`](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/blob/79fa2e81e690b9c32882d006a6799c3a316fe346/seleniumwire/request.py#L155) and it doesn't have `.json()`.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I assumed they depended on requests.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use these 3 steps

```py
# I define the scopes to avoid other post requests that are not related
# we can also use it to only select the required endpoints
driver.scopes = [
     # .* is a regex stands for any char 0 or more times
    '.*stackoverflow.*',
    '.*github.*'
]

# visit the page
driver.get('LINK')

# get the response
response = driver.last_request # or driver.requests[-1]

# get the json
js = json.loads(
    decode(
        response.response.body,
        # get the encoding from the request
        response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'),
    )
)

# this clears all the requests it's a good idea to do after each visit to the page
del driver.requests
```

for more info here is the [doc](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)